# java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString

Tags: java, string, exception, numberformatexception

I'm trying to convert my binary string to decimal value but i'm getting error.
The binary string is of 32 bits so no case of overflow.

```
String s = "11111111111111111111111111111101";
System.out.print(s.length());
System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(s,2));
```

Exception is:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11111111111111111111111111111101"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Integer` type is not big as you expect, instead, try to use `BigInteger`:

```
new BigInteger(s, 2)
```

Output

```
324294967293
```

Answer (score 0):

The first bit is 1, so this number cannot be represented as a positive int. If you try, it will "overflow" and become negative.

If that is what you want, you can [parse the string as an unsigned value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-int-):

```
System.out.print(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(s,2));
```

Output: -3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `long`:

```
String s = "11111111111111111111111111111101";
System.out.print(s.length());
System.out.print(Long.parseLong(s,2));
```